# Identifying presence of FamilySearch Person Notes (API)

Tags: familysearch.org

I am successfully using the browser-based FamilySearch APIs (/platform/tree/persons/...) to obtain Person, Person Memories, Person Sources, and Person Notes information in JSON format.

I am not doing this on a person-by-person basis, but driven by the output of a FS Family Tree search (also automated via the browser-based API).

It is easy to identify from the main Person JSON whether Person Memories and/or Person Sources information is present, so that I can limit my relevant API calls to those that are actually going to return something.

Person Notes are causing me a problem since I have failed to identify any 'Notes present' information in the main Person JSON (there is a URL for the Notes information, but this is present whether there are actually any Notes available or not).

I cannot find a FamilySearch forum on which to post this (or any other API) question, not being formally registered as a developer there (I am working on that, but the bar is high). (They don't seem to handle API questions on the main FS Community forums, and this point is not, as far as I can see, covered in the FS API documentation.)

If anyone has found a way of identifying the presence of Person Notes from the Person JSON (or in some other way), it would be v useful to hear about it - thank you.

Comment: TIL there are APIs for this stuff! Are you calling these APIs from the browser, or are you using a separate application like Postman, or something on the command line like curl or wget?

Comment: Do you have the FSID of an example person who has Person Notes? I have lots of examples that don't have notes.

Comment: Thanks, GWHZ-HLD has a Note. I am running it using Python and Selenium to get a logged-in session, then using javascript to issue my Get requests with an Accept application/json header set.

Comment: It looks to me like /platform/tree/persons/(id)/memories acts the same as /platform/tree/persons/(id)/notes. How are you detecting the presence of memories, and can you detect notes the same way?

Comment: Hi, memories have snippets like this in the main Person JSON: "evidence" : [ { ... "resource" :  "https://www.familysearch.org/platform/memories/memories/169643613/personas/169643613-51825605" - I just use the existence of such entry(ies) as the indicator. There is (as far as I can see) nothing like that for notes.

Comment: One positive point is that the 'version' timestamp on the Person JSON does seem to be updated if a Note is added/changed (or, at least, I have no Notes where the 'attributionmodified' timestamp is higher than the Person's 'version', and in fact quite a few where the values are exactly the same, indicating that the Notes modification has triggered a Person 'version' update).